# Selecting a column from a subquery by its alias name generates error

Tags: mysql, syntax, mariadb

In particular, I want to select a column from a subquery by its alias name but this generates an error.  I refer to this line in particular, from the full query below:

```
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT x.minid (SELECT p.post_title, MIN(m.id) as minid, m.meta_value
...) as x );
```

> ```
> create table wp_posts (
>   ID integer primary key auto_increment,
>   post_title varchar(30),
>   post_type varchar(30)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table wp_postmeta (
>   ID integer primary key auto_increment,
>   post_id integer,
>   meta_key varchar(30) not null default '_regular_price',
>   meta_value integer not null
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into wp_posts (post_title, post_type) values
> ('Apple Pie','Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('Shepards Pie','Product'),
> ('Jam Pie','Product'),
> ('Jam Pie','Product'),
> ('Plate','Not a Product'),
> ('Bucket','Not a Product'),
> ('Chequebook','Not a Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_value) values
> (1,10),
> (2,5),
> (3,9),
> (4,8),
> (5,11),
> (6,12),
> (7,10),
> (8,6),
> (9,1),
> (10,1),
> (11,7),
> (12,2),
> (13,2);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> -- Deleting all duplicate products in wp_posts table 
> DELETE FROM wp_posts 
> WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT x.minid (SELECT p.post_title, MIN(m.id) as minid, m.meta_value
> FROM 
>     wp_postmeta m
>     INNER JOIN wp_posts p 
>         ON  p.id = m.post_id
>         AND p.post_type = 'Product' 
> WHERE 
>     m.meta_key = '_regular_price'
>     AND NOT EXISTS (
>         SELECT 1
>         FROM 
>             wp_postmeta m1
>             INNER JOIN wp_posts p1
>                 ON  p1.id = m1.post_id
>                 AND p1.post_type = 'Product'
>         WHERE 
>             m1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
>             AND p1.post_title = p.post_title
>             AND m1.meta_value < m.meta_value
>      )
>  GROUP BY p.post_title, m.meta_value) as x
>  );
> ```
>
> ```
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT p.post_title, MIN(m.id) as minid, m.meta_value
> FROM 
>     wp_postmeta m
>   ' at line 3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=994c7a45d2de1294538121bfe31df83b)*

If it can't be done because of syntax rules, how *would* I select the aggregate column `MIN(m.id)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed from keyword in one of the subquery.

WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT x.minid **from** (SELECT p.post_title, MIN(m.id) as minid, m.meta_value
...) as x );

Comment: I was so preoccupied with it not being allowed I overlooked something more basic.  You are right.  I can accept your answer, but if the downvotes start piling on, I will have to ask a moderator to delete this question.  But I thank you for your solution!